# Using only elementary row operations, how do I show that two duplicate columns yield a zero column?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The analogous statement in terms of duplicate rows is easy, as we can produce a zero row by one single row operation which subtracts one of the duplicates from the other. But, given a matrix which is such that it has duplicate columns, how do I show that this matrix is row-equivalent to a matrix which has a zero column? I am doing this as I am adding some notes to Hoffman and Kunze Chapter 1 for simple cases in which one can see by inspection that a matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Ah, I see. Would you mind showing how @User ?

Comment: Two $n\times m$ matrices are row-equivalent if and only if they have the same null space. So as a matter of fact a matrix is row-equivalent to a matrix with a zero column if and only if it already has a zero column, and your claim is false.

Comment: @EE18 sorry, the first part of my comment was correct, but on second thought the second part is not necessarily correct (might not get an entirely zero row from the fact that there is a duplicate column, e.g. consider a $2\times 5$ matrix with duplicate columns which has rank $2$ - such a matrix can be constructed). That's why I removed my comment.

Comment: Ah, wow I wouldn't have expected that. So I can conclude from a zero column that a matrix is not invertible but if a matrix has duplicate columns, it may still be invertible? @SassatelliGiulio This seems to not be true though?

Comment: @EE18 No, a matrix with two identical columns can't be invertible, but it doesn't have to be row-equivalent to a matrix with a zero column either.

Comment: I see @SassatelliGiulio So at the level of what I know, for this duplicate column I would simply have to continue row-reducing the matrix to its reduced row echelon form and verify that it is not the identity matrix in order to prove its invertible. I could not use the corresponding argument for duplicate rows, wherein that leads to me a zero row which is a noninvertible matrix?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I think it is true that a matrix with duplicate columns must be row-equivalent to a amtrix with a zero row (namely, its row echelon form, for else it is row equivalent to the identity matrix and is invertible), but is there any way to show that directly? That is, without arguing that duplicate columns implies not invertible which then implies row-equivalent to some matrix with a zero row? Is there a way to skip the middle there, i.e. to show that duplicate columns implies row-equivalent to a zero row simply by explicit row operations?

Comment: the shorthand is that the row rank equals the column rank. This is true for rectangular matrices as well. For square $A,$   we find $A$ is singular if and only if $A^T$   is nonsingular. Here is one version https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295243/elementary-row-operations-do-not-alter-the-no-of-linearly-independent-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Sassatelli Giullio, it is not true that if a (square) matrix has two identical columns then it can be row-reduced to have a zero column. (In fact, this is very uncommon; the original matrix needs to have a zero column already, since row operations preserve the nullspace.) For instance it's not hard to see that $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\2&2 \end{bmatrix}$ cannot be row-reduced to make either column zero.

In the comments the followup question was posed of whether it can be row-reduced to have a zero *row*, which is what I address here. We take a totally matrix-theoretic approach that also avoids any kind of "invertible matrix theorems".

---

Suppose that we have an $n\times n$ matrix with the first two columns identical. If they are zero columns there is nothing to do. Otherwise, permute the rows so that these columns' first entries are nonzero. When performing Gaussian elimination on the first column, note that this also converts all the non-first entries of the second column to zero. This means that the second column cannot have a pivot (a first nonzero entry in its row).

Every column has at most one pivot after Guassian elimination is complete, otherwise one of the pivots is lower and should have been zeroed out. Therefore, there are at most $n-1$ pivots, and so some row has no pivot. But this means that that row has no first nonzero entry; in other words, it is a zero row.

---

About the assumptions on the matrix $A$:

- If $A$ is not square, the statement is true for uninteresting reasons when there are more rows than columns (i.e. the repeated column doesn't matter), and false when there are more columns than rows. Counterexamples are easily found, including silly ones like $\big[~1~~1~\big]$.
- If $A$ has two columns identical which are not the first two, the argument can be salvaged by using a modification of Gaussian elimination tailored for this matrix: instead of prioritizing columns left-to-right, place the top priority on one of the duplicate columns, then prioritize zeros out the first, second, and so on. The definition of a pivot is more tedious in this setting, but everything goes through fine.
- This argument can also be extended to show that if the first $k$ columns of a matrix are linearly dependent, a zero row can be formed. There is more to track, but the idea is the same: the $k^\text{th}$ column will fail to have a pivot. This is a justification for the [usual algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces#Example_2) to compute column spaces.
- To follow on Will Jagy's comment, the number of pivots of a matrix after Gaussian elimination is usually called its rank (although authors define it in many ways), which is both the row and the column rank. The only point when we used the fact that $A$ was square is to conclude that some row had no pivot, so the argument can be recycled to prove theorems in that case as well.